# Неизвестные директории в GIT

Tags: git

В GIT появилась странные изменения с неизвестной директорий, такой просто нет.

```
 deleted:    "domains \342\200\224 \321\217\321\200\320\273\321\213\320\272.lnk"
```

При попытке отмены  `git checkout` выдаёт

```
error: pathspec 'domains \342\200\224 \321\217\321\200\320\273\321\213\320\272.lnk' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

При попытке добавления `git add .`

```
fatal: pathspec 'domains \342\200\224 \321\217\321\200\320\273\321\213\320\272.lnk' did not match any files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По порядку:

1. Это не папка, это файл с расширением `.lnk`
2. Такие изменения говорят о том, что файл был удален, поэтому вы его и не видите.
3. Имя файла содержит символы, которые не может нормально отобразить git, скорее всего это просто русские буквы. Скопировать из статуса git имя не получится, чтоб вернуть его командой `git checkout`.

Самый быстрый вариант убрать такие изменения это выполнить `git reset --hard`, но будьте осторожны, эта команда уничтожит и другие изменения в репозитории не включенные в коммит (если такие есть).

Comment: были подозрения что это скорее всего не директория, а список файлов.